# converting files into base64 string using FileReader in angular

Tags: angular, filereader

I am using FileReader to read upload files as base64 string and store them in a string property of an array of items in an object in angular 11. After completion of this process I am printing this object which shows that all the files are converted into base64 strings and placed in object successfully. but when I post this object to asp.net web api it shows empty string there just in FileAsBase64 string property. All other values are same as posted. Please help me to fix this. my angular code is given below.

```
mapFormToItemBarcodeDTO(): any {
let _package = new PackageBarcodeDTO();
_package.WayBillNo = this.itemForm.get('wayBillNo')?.value;
_package.ItemBarcodes = new Array<ItemBarcodeDTO>();

this.thePackages.controls.forEach((element, index) => {
let itemBarcode = new ItemBarcodeDTO();

itemBarcode.ItemID = element.get('itemId')?.value;
itemBarcode.PackageID = element.get('packageId')?.value;

itemBarcode.Items = [];
let items = this.thePackages.at(index).get('items') as FormArray;
items.controls.forEach((element, index) => {
let item = new ItemDTO();
item.Barcode = element.get('barcode')?.value;
item.Weight = element.get('weight')?.value;
item.Size = element.get('size')?.value;
item.ItemStatusID = element.get('status')?.value;

this.uploadFiles.forEach(element => {

if (element.Index == index && element.ItemId == itemBarcode.ItemID) 
{
item.FileName = (String)(element.FileToUpload?.name);
item.FileType = (String)(element.FileToUpload?.type);

let reader = new FileReader();

// Setup onload event for reader
reader.onload = function (e) {
// Store base64 encoded representation of file
item.FileAsBase64 = (String)(e.target?.result);
}
// Read the file
reader.readAsDataURL(element.FileToUpload);

}
});
itemBarcode.Items.push(item);

});
_package.ItemBarcodes.push(itemBarcode);
});

console.log(_package)
return _package;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting Files To Base64 In Angular

```
export class AppComponent  {
  base64Output : string;

  onFileSelected(event) {
    this.convertFile(event.target.files[0]).subscribe(base64 => {
      this.base64Output = base64;
    });
  }

  convertFile(file : File) : Observable<string> {
    const result = new ReplaySubject<string>(1);
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    reader.onload = (event) => result.next(btoa(event.target.result.toString()));
    return result;
  }
}
```

https://tutorialsforangular.com/2020/12/17/converting-files-to-base64-in-angular/

Comment: Please upon sending the message to the subject, complete the subject to prevent possible memory leak